# VCenter 7.0 - Error downloading plug-in. Make sure that the URL is reachable and the registered thumbprint is correct. Initiator:

Tags: vcenter

I have been getting this error lately.

Download plug-in
Status:
Error downloading plug-in. Make sure that the URL is reachable and the registered thumbprint is correct.
Initiator:
VSPHERE.LOCAL\vsphere-webclient-192f42a9-0951-466c-8d24-ee850c197519

When I go to Administration > Client Plugins:

com.vmware.h4.vsphere.client
0.4.0.0
Failed
Unknown
N/A
N/A

Comment: Also I don't have the option to enable or disable the plugin

Answer (score 3):

**Error Message:** *Error downloading plug-in. Make sure that the URL is reachable and the registered thumbprint is correct.* [Error Image: com.vmware.h4.vsphere.client-0.4.0.0-plugin-failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXxaC.png)

I had the same problem, and it looks like an obsolete plugin. I'm using vSphere Version:    **7.0.1 Build 17327586**

- Product: VMware vCenter Server Version: 7.0.1.00200  Build number: 17327517
- Hypervisor: VMware ESXi Version: 7.0.1 Build
  number: 17325551

****Before** attempting any of the following*: If possible, shut down your **VCSA** and take a **snapshot**.*

You can unregister the obsolete plugin with **lstool.py** script.

1. **SSH** into the **VCSA** and launch **BASH**.
2. **Verify** both the obsolete and current versions of the **com.vmware.h4.vsphere.client plugin**.

> Type the following command:
>
> **`find / -name *h4.vsphere.client-0.4.*`**

*The output should look like this*:

```
/etc/vmware/vsphere-ui/cm-service-packages/com.vmware.cis.vsphereclient.plugin/com.vmware.h4.vsphere.client-0.4.0.0
/etc/vmware/vsphere-ui/cm-service-packages/com.vmware.cis.vsphereclient.plugin/com.vmware.h4.vsphere.client-0.4.0.0/com.vmware.h4.vsphere.client-0.4.0.0.esa
/etc/vmware/vsphere-ui/cm-service-packages/com.vmware.cis.vsphereclient.plugin/com.vmware.h4.vsphere.client-0.4.0.0/com.vmware.h4.vsphere.client-0.4.0.0.zip
-----------------------------------------------------------
/etc/vmware/vsphere-ui/cm-service-packages/com.vmware.cis.vsphereclient.plugin/com.vmware.h4.vsphere.client-0.4.1.0
/etc/vmware/vsphere-ui/cm-service-packages/com.vmware.cis.vsphereclient.plugin/com.vmware.h4.vsphere.client-0.4.1.0/com.vmware.h4.vsphere.client-0.4.1.0.esa
/etc/vmware/vsphere-ui/cm-service-packages/com.vmware.cis.vsphereclient.plugin/com.vmware.h4.vsphere.client-0.4.1.0/com.vmware.h4.vsphere.client-0.4.1.0.zip
```

3. **Find** the plugin **Service ID** for **Version 0.4.0.0**

> Type the following command:
>
> **`/usr/lib/vmware-lookupsvc/tools/lstool.py list --ep-type com.vmware.cis.vsphereclient.plugin --url http://localhost:7090/lookupservice/sdk`**

*The output should look like this*:

```
Service Product: com.vmware.h4
Service Type: vsphere.client
Service ID: 846a9473-912f-443f-b657-4603f15a9fd8
Site ID: default-site
Node ID: 038505b7-e2fb-40d1-aa15-141c2600fd2d
Owner ID: vsphere-webclient-bc0dc187-7d31-1821-8c32-9c0g589c13b8@vsphere.local
Version: 0.4.0.0
Endpoints:
Type: com.vmware.cis.vsphereclient.plugin
Protocol: http
URL: https://vcsa:443/ui/plugins/h4va.zip
SSL trust: ***
Attributes:
com.vmware.cis.cm.HostId: ba0fc187-9d81-18d1-8a39-5f0f253c24b5
-------------------------------------------------------
Service Product: com.vmware.h4
Service Type: vsphere.client
Service ID: cb7deda1-35af-357f-6f8b-3cf05324ca7c
Site ID: default-site
Node ID: 012605c7-e2eb-46e1-aa17-121c2810fa2f
Owner ID: vsphere-webclient-bc0gb186-3d31-38d1-8c37-9a0f553c1235@vsphere.local
Version: 0.4.1.0
Endpoints:
Type: com.vmware.cis.vsphereclient.plugin
Protocol: http
URL: https://vcsa:443/ui/plugin-resources/h4va.zip
SSL trust: ***
Attributes:
com.vmware.cis.cm.HostId: bc0dc187-9d81-78d1-8c35-9f03352c14c5
```

4. **Unregister** the obsolete plugin using **lstool.py** using the plugin **Service ID**.

**Note:** The ***user*** and ***password*** must be enclosed by **back quotes/backticks ( ` )**.

**Note:** In this example, the **value** for **--id** is from the example noted in **Step 3**. You will need to replace the **value** shown for **your version of the plugin**.

> Type the following command:
>
> **`/usr/lib/vmware-lookupsvc/tools/lstool.py unregister --url http://localhost:7090/lookupservice/sdk --user 'administrator@vsphere.local' --password 'yourpassword' --id 846a9473-912f-443f-b657-4603f15a9fd8 --no-check-cert`**

5. Restart the HTML5 Web UI.

> Type the following command:
>
> **`vmon-cli -r vsphere-ui`**

6. Perform **Step 2** and **Step 3** to **verify the removal**
   of the obsolete **com.vmware.h4.vsphere.client-0.4.0.0 plugin**.